# Angularjs Constant not working with controller Inline Annotation

Tags: angularjs, constants

I created  a constant but it's showing undefined when I add [ ] to the controller. When I remove it, the constant works. Please am I missing anything?

```
app.constant('RESOURCES', (function() {
  var resource = '';
  return {
    USERS_DOMAIN: resource,
    API: resource + 'q',
    BASIC_INFO: resource + '/api/info'
  }
})());
```

-When the constant is called in this controller, it doesn't work:

```
 app.controller('SampleCtr', ['$scope','RESOURCES', function($scope, RESOURCES){
   console.log(RESOURCES) // undefined
}]);
```

-This one below works because I remove the [ ] and the sad news is that the below approach doesn't work when minified.

```
app.controller('SampleCtr', function($scope, RESOURCES){
   console.log(RESOURCES) // undefined
});
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/hy14SrH9LAyb7bedqUBk?p=preview. Do you perhaps have another provider named *"RESOURCES"*

Comment: I've checked over and over again. No!

Comment: It is working fine even for the code you shared, please refer plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/NXdsea2WmyONHLsCyOxp?p=preview  If there is something else please share for further investigation

Comment: Thank you. It's actually part of a large code (many controllers from different files). @ddedigne solution worked. I still can't figure out what is happening. $injection worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the second approach work by using [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) and writing it like this :

```
app.controller('SampleCtr', SampleCtr);

/* @ngInject */

function SampleCtr($scope, RESOURCES){ 
    console.log(RESOURCES);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It worked but without the inline annotation, minification broke the code. When added: app.controller('SampleCtr', ['$scope, 'RESOURCES', SampleCtr]), it works great. Thanks!!!